Laravel/Filament: don't show 'Create & create another' button on relationmanager
Suppose I have a ProductResource with a form. When I create a product, a button with “Create & create another” appears. I only want the “Create” button, so in ProductResource -> Pages -> CreateProduct.php I add "protected static bool $canCreateAnother = false;" Now the “Create & create another” button is not shown (correct). I also have CategoryResource with ProductsRelationManager. I want to hide the “Create & create another” in the ProductsRelationManager as well, but since a relationmanager has no pages I can't add "protected static bool $canCreateAnother = false;" to the code.
Is it possible to hide this button in the relation manager?

You can use this code in your ProductsRelationManager
->headerActions([
    Tables\Actions\CreateAction::make()
      ->createAnother(false)
])

My filament version is 3.2.69

headerActions can only be applied to a table. I  want to hide the button “Create & create another” on te form of de ProductsRelationManager

This does not hide it in the form page

If I add this I get 2 "Create new" button on the table form ??

CreateAction::make()->disableCreateAnother()


Where do you add this line?
